# How to make unique pointers to polymorphic classes using the ternary operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, conditional-operator

I'm trying to set a variable using the ternary operator. However, the compiler is complaining about incompatible types. I'm sure there is a way to do this. I have tried static casting to the base class, but I haven't been able to get the correct syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void test() {std::cout << "A" << std::endl;} 
};

struct B: public A
{
    void test() final {std::cout << "B" << std::endl;} 
};

struct C: public A
{
    void test() final {std::cout << "C" << std::endl;} 
};

int main()
{
    bool t = true;
    // Try to cast try a base unique class ptr. Maybe use static_cast??
    std::unique_ptr<A> aptr = t ? std::make_unique<B>(): std::make_unique<C>();
    aptr->test();
}
```

Comment: The type of the expressions on both sides of the `:` *must* either be the same or at least convertible between each other. In your case they aren't so you simply can't use the ternary expression. Which IMO is a good thing, because it tends to make code harder to read and therefore harder to maintain.

Comment: +1 @Someprogrammerdude funny that you mention readability. I spent an hour chasing down a bug from this exact bit of code because I flipped the logical operation. It took me longer to recognize the issue because the ternary operator made it harder to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return value of ternary expression is the common type of both expressions (in fact `std::common_type` might use ternary operator as part of its implementation :-) ).

Whereas `std::unique_ptr<B>` and `std::unique_ptr<C>` are unrelated types,

both `std::unique_ptr<B>` and `std::unique_ptr<C>` are convertible to `std::unique_ptr<A>`, so converting one explicitly would be enough:

```
auto aptr = t ? std::unique_ptr<A>{std::make_unique<B>()}
              : std::make_unique<C>();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W6J9Qy)

Comment: @AProgrammer: Demo added. and yes it can `std::unique_ptr<C>` is convertible to `std::unique_ptr<A>`

Comment: @AProgrammer you don't need the same type on each side, you only need one type to be convertible to the other, or both type being convertible to a common primitive type.

Comment: @Jarod42, my bad.  It seems I can't read code anymore.  Time to go home.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> aptr = t ? std::unique_ptr<A>(new B()): std::unique_ptr<A>(new C());
```